# eigenvectors and eigenvalues of rotation by theta

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the following matrix representing counterclockwise rotation by (theta) around the origin

[image]

Comment: Show us what you tried. Do you know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of any matrix? This will be no different.

Comment: det(lambda(I) - Q) = (lambda)^2 - 2Lambdacosx +1

sorry dont know how to do symbols but the problem is i do not know what angel it is rotating bby hence i get stuck on how to factor the polynomial

Comment: Yep. So you want to solve $0=\lambda^2-2\lambda\cos(\theta)+1=0.$ Do you know how to solve this? Try the quadratic formula and leave $\theta$ as is.

Comment: no i believe not 
dont we need a theta given to us for that?

Comment: No. Why would you? Why can't your eigenvalues be in terms of $\theta$?

Answer (score 2):

**For the eigenvalues.**

Treat this as just an ordinary matrix, and don't worry about what $\theta$ is. The characteristic polynomial for this matrix is 
$$c(\lambda)=\lambda^2-2\lambda\cos\theta+1.$$
You can solve  $c(\lambda)=0$ using the quadratic formula, and just treat $\theta$ as constant. You'll notice that this will give you 
\begin{align*}
\lambda&=\frac{2\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{4\cos^2\theta-4}}{2}\\
&=\frac{2\cos\theta\pm 2\sqrt{\cos^2\theta-1}}{2}\\
&=\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{-\sin^2\theta}\\
\end{align*}
So $\lambda_1=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ and $\lambda_2=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Can you find the eigenvectors now?

Comment: so for λ1(I) - Q = −isinθ  -sinθ
                             sinθ −isinθ

and then we find the RREF to find eigenvectors, correct?